# Можно ли с нуля зарабатывать на создании приложений в Play Market?

Tags: java, android, google-play, мобильные-приложения

Я начинающий Android разработчик, уже написал несколько приложений и сходил на несколько собеседований.
В связи с тем, что в текущей ситуации искать работу в офисе стало значительно сложнее, решил попробовать писать приложения для Play Market. Вопрос тем, кто чем-то подобным уже занимался (занимается), насколько это реально в плане получения дохода, хотя бы в перспективе?

Comment: лет 10 назад ещё было реально. Сейчас маловероятно

Comment: Вас быстрее забанят, чем вы что то заработаете. Вот тут много информации о банах: https://dont-play-with-google.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Все реально. Вопрос только в том что вы напишете?

Важно не просто писать приложение, а решать какую-то проблему пользователей, желательно чтоб это не была проблема вроде "Посмотреть погоду", т.к. таких приложений десятки и они более оптмизированны. Решите проблему - получить результат.

Но только нужно помнить о нескольких вещах:

- приложение скорее всего потребует какой-то бэкенд (если это не фонарик) и вам необходимо будет решить эту проблему. В целом есть множество публичных API но с этими API другая штука, раз они написаны, вероятно под них уже есть свой сервис и ваше приложение должно быть лучше или отличаться чем-то уникальным от этого сервиса, чтоб им кто-то захотел пользоваться.
- раз у вас нет опыта, вы скорее всего страшно "наговнокодите" и спустя пол года +- вам будет очень тяжело это поддерживать.

Ну и в целом если рассматривать приложение в PlayMarket как способ заработка то надо понимать - это стартап и его успех зависит от идеи и реализации. Просто писать что-то чтоб заработать условно N денег в месяц наверное не самая простая идея, хотя я знаю тех кто к примеру пишет простенькие игры и зарабатывает на них ( с оговоркой, они все же имеют основную работу)

Если говорить о заработке, вы можете попробовать податься в фриланс и там начать что-то зарабатывать, но тут есть свои *"но"*:

- вы берете на себя ответственность перед заказчиком за результат.
- скорость вашего роста будет намного ниже чем в хорошей команде, т.к. вы можете писать страшный "говнокод" и никто вам об этом не скажет. Хорошая команда дает очень круто буст к знаниям.
- ну и это нестабильность. Вас могут кинуть, у вас может быть работа сегодня, а завтра нет. Но с другой стороны можно и наткнуться на хорошего заказчика и с ним работать 100500 лет.

Насчет того что сейчас сложнее найти работу? Ну вопрос спорный. Просто конкуренция больше и наверн работодателя стоит чем-то зацепить. А так многие серьезные компании сейчас вообще не снижают темпов, а кто-то даже наращивает.

Comment: А еще совет: Хотите найти работу? Открываете HeadHunter или любой другой сервис и шлете свое резюме на все вакансии где написано "Android" даже если там требуется опыт 3+ года. Я в свое время делал тоже самое и почти все приглашения на собеседование приходили от вакансий для которых требовался опыт и получил свой оффер именно на такой вакансии. А совет №2: Заведите страничку LinkedIn и поработайте над ней. Есть куча видео и статей как это сделать и почему это полезно.

Answer (score 2):

Если зарабатывать несколько $ в месяц, то реально.

Готовы ли вы конкурировать с миллионами программистов по всему миру выпускающими тысячи приложений ежедневно?

Готовы ли вы конкурировать с миллионами "reskiner"'ов, а попросту мошенников, клонирующими все и вся и выпускающие тысячи приложений ежедневно?

Готовы ли вы, что все ваши идеи и решения будут содраны и выданы за свои а на все ваши стенания к Google'у вам предложат судиться за свой счет на прямую?

Готовы?

Ну тогда добро пожаловать.
Если вы взрослый человек, то не слушайте истории "про розовых слоников".

Вывод: если вам нравится эта работа, то лучше пробовать (с большой вероятностью провала) в свободное от основной работы время.